# Extending a breeze entity using TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, breeze, hottowel

I am developing a website using HotTowel and TypeScript.  In John Papa's excellent PluralSight course, he extended a breezejs entity by creating a constructor and using 'Object.defineProperty' to extend it.  For example, he added a property called `fullName` as follows.

NB: metadataStore is the breezejs metadata store

```
function registerPerson(metadataStore) {
        metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Person', Person);

        function Person() {
            this.isPartial = false;
            this.isSpeaker = false;
        }

        Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, 'fullName', {
            get: function () {
                var fn = this.firstName;
                var ln = this.lastName;
                return ln ? fn + ' ' + ln : fn;
            }
        });
    }
```

My question is how would I achieve the same using TypeScript ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript support accessor out of the box. The TypeScript code you asked could be :

```
function registerPerson(metadataStore) {
    metadataStore.registerEntityTypeCtor('Person', Person);
}
class Person {
    public firstName: string;
    public lastName: string;

    constructor(public isPartial=false, public isSpeaker=false) {
    }

    get fullName():string {
        return `${this.firstName} ${this.lastName}`;
    }
}
```