# Generate metadata from interface breeze+Typescript

Tags: typescript, entity, breeze

I have some models, and i want to use them in typescript, so that breeze can consume those models and build `metadataStore`, but don't know what to do, there is some methods to add properties by hand, but i want to build `metadataStore` from existing model

This is my typescript interfaces which were generated by T4TS

```
/** Generated from Twine.Infrastructure.Entity **/
export interface IEntity extends breeze.Entity {
  _id: number;
  _created_at?: string;
  _updated_at?: string;
}
/** Generated from Twine.Infrastructure.Models.Ingredient **/
export interface IIngredient extends twine.Model.IEntity {
  Price?: number;
  Name: string;
  Description: string;
}
```

This `extends breeze.Entity` was added by me indeed.

And this is service that should get metadata from `T` and return single result by id

```
Get<T>( key:string,  successCallback: Function, failCallback?: Function ): void {
  var type = new breeze.EntityType(); //what should be here???
  var entityKey = new breeze.EntityKey(type, key);
  this.manager.fetchEntityByKey(entityKey)
    .then( ( data: breeze.EntityByKeyResult ) => { successCallback( data ) })
    .catch( ( reason: any ) => {
      if ( failCallback ) {
        failCallback( reason );
      }
    });
}
```

So `new breeze.EntityType();` this constructor accepts `EntityTypeOptions` and it looks like

```
interface EntityTypeOptions {
    shortName?: string;
    namespace?: string;
    autoGeneratedKeyType?: AutoGeneratedKeyType;
    defaultResourceName?: string;
    dataProperties?: DataProperty[];
    navigationProperties?: NavigationProperty[];
}
```

So where do i add my existing `IEntity` models? So that i wouldn't need to build them from `EntityTypeOptions`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is your server technology? Are you using Entity Framework on the server? If so, the metadata would come from the server. You extract it in your Web API controller through the EFContextProvider as illustrated here:

http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/efcontextprovider

Then on the client you would generate TS classes for each of your entity types and register the ctors with Breeze. You can find an example in this related question.

[Extending a breeze entity using TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29041959/extending-a-breeze-entity-using-typescript)

Generating just interfaces won't get you very far as interfaces have no meaning at runtime in TS. They are only useful during development time.

Comment: take a look here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29058810/is-there-any-angularjs-asp-net-webapi-odata-breeze-js-typescript-example/29066931#29066931

Comment: Yeah i use entityframework, but guess breeze is misconfigured